# Enable GZIP Compression in PhoneGap App?

Tags: javascript, cordova, compression, gzip, phonegap-build

I want to use GZIP compression for data transmissions over a network in PhoneGap App.

I know there is multiple solution for Web app/site but i could not find any solution for PhoneGap App?

Thanks in advance for any help.